# Wake on Lan expiring

Tags: networking, windows-10, sleep, wake-on-lan

router:
Netgear r7000

Proper port forwarding enabled, dyndns working

Motherboard: Msi z170a gaming m5

Wake on lan enabled via BIOS

OS:
Win10 64 bit

Wake on lan enabled in driver

Problem:
wake on lan not working after some time (overnight)

local linux server is also not able to wake server via ether-wake on same subnet

Wake on lan works (both local subnet+remote) immediately and shortly (under 1 hour) after system goes to sleep. I have not tested how long after sleep/shutdown the function stops working

Troubleshooting attempted:
Static arp entry added to router via telenable

Any help appreciated